# Converting JSON to table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a table that stores JSON as:

[image]

Now, I am looking to flatten this data in SQL to something like this:

[image]

I tried using OPENJSON but not quite able to make it work. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working! Thanks!

```
SELECT Rollno,
t.Value AS Subject
from [Students] 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Subjects, '$.subjects') t
```

Comment: A good practice to add a condition in the last line to validate whether it's JSON. Put this Where ISJSON(Subjects) = 1